# Routing on React Next js and Auth0, stuck on 'isLoading'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Please bare with me. I started my first project with Nextjs and I'm getting stuck due to routing. I'm using auth0 as the logic for login, however I think I messed up somewhere.

First this is a Nextjs proyect with the App root directory (not src). In the App folder it shows

layout.js

```
import { UserProvider } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <html lang="es">
        <body>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

page.js

```
"use client";
import Login from "./components/login";
import React from "react";
import { UserProvider, useUser } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();
  if (isLoading)
    return (
      <>
        <div>Cargando Index...</div> // here is where it gets stuck, no screen is further loaded
      </>
    );

  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        Welcome {user.name}! <Link href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <div className="mx-auto sm:max-w-none md:max-w-sm lg:max-w-xl xl:max-w-2xl">
        <Login />
      </div>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

And then I created a pages folder which contains api/auth/[auth0]/route.js

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
export const GET = handleAuth();
```

Also in pages I created _app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { UserProvider ,} from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <UserProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </UserProvider>
      );
   }
```

and main.js (which is the page it should go after correct credentials from auth0 authentication. The user enters by root (/) and auth0 should trigger directly there, or that's what I pretend the behaviour to be. Then after credentials move to /main.

main.js

```
import React from "react";
import BasicLayout from "@/app/layouts/BasicLayout";
import HeadDatePicker from "@/app/components/main/HeadDatePicker";
import { IoSettingsOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import Link from "next/link";
import { UserProvider,useUser } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";

const Main = () => {

  const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();

    return (
      <BasicLayout>
        <div className="bg-stone-200/75 shadow text-black h-10 flex items-center justify-center">
          <div className="flex justify-start w-full mx-2">‍: DriverName</div>
          <div className="flex justify-start w-full mx-2">: CarModel</div>
          <div className="ml-auto mx-2 shadow rounded-md bg-stone-200 cursor-pointer">
            <IoSettingsOutline size={30} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-white shadow rounded-xl text-black m-4">
          <HeadDatePicker />
          Welcome {user?.name}! <Link href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</Link>
        </div>
      </BasicLayout>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

However, since this framework is new to me and it seems they have changed recently the way of working, I'm most probably mixing documentation concepts and I believe the proyect is mixed up. Worth mentioning that I have to work with a php shared server and I have no control over it so most of the tasks that Next seems to do on server side I pretty much believe I will need to do them in the client side with 'use client' instruction.